# Video Streaming in android using webview

Tags: android

In my application I want to stream video from url. Video is playing perfectly.When user click on that webview its redirect to video's url and showing an alertdialog "Complete action Using" where user can download that video by clicking the option Internet.I want to restrict that means user only watch that video but can not download that. I want user to watch that video using android default player. Thanks in advance.

```
public class PlayVideo extends Activity {

    private String vUrl, vName;
    private WebView webView;
    Button back, home;
    TextView videoName;
    Vibrator vibrator;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // For full screen
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.videoplay);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView01);
        back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bBack);
        home = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bHome);
        videoName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVidName);
        // for vibration when a button clicked
        vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        // getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                vibrator.vibrate(40);
                finish();
            }
        });


        vName = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoname");
        videoName.setText(vName);
        vUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("vid_url");
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Log.i("fired url", vUrl);
        webView.loadUrl(vUrl);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by launching a specific application for streaming the video.

**BUT NOTE:**

- users with only 1 suitable video app, will not see the dialog.
- Also,
  users that have set a default video app, will not see the dialog
  either.

Hence, I would not limit myself, by launching a specific video application, and instead let the android users have a nice android experience.

***Should*** you have ***very good*** reasons to launch a specific video player, you can use:

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.mxtech.videoplayer.ad"); // Will launch MX player
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("your_path"), "video/*");
    startActivity(intent);
} catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
    // the app mxplayer was not found...
    Toast.makeText(this, "mx player is not installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```